# Error 424 - Object Not Found - For only one user

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, office-automation

I have an Access 2010 application that creates Excel spreadsheets.  It's been working perfectly for months but suddenly one user gets "Error 424: Object Not Found."  It had worked for her one week and then failed the next.  As far as we can tell, there have been no updates to her computer.

I created a test application and have pasted the code below.  It works for everyone except this one user.  The line throwing the error is "xl.Application.Visible = True" and I presume that's because the line before it didn't create the object like it should have.

```
Private Sub cmdTest_Click()

    Dim xl As Object
    Dim ws As Object

    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    xl.Application.Visible = True  ' <-- This line throws the error
    xl.Visible = True
    xl.Interactive = True

    Set ws = xl.Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)
    ws.Range("A1").Formula = "Test"

End Sub
```

I've tried putting loop in to waste a couple seconds in hopes it would give enough time to create the object, but that didn't help.  I also checked the References on her machine, but nothing's missing.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: check `xl` references ( null )?

Comment: I tried adding "If IsNull(xl) Then" after the CreateObject line, but now the CreateObject line itself is throwing the 424 error.  Weird.

Comment: You should check `Object` variables to be not `Nothing`: If xl Is Nothing then...    Check if there is `Excel.Application` class definition in windows registry.

Comment: Why not add references to Excel Object Model and use early binding? ie. `Dim xlApp as Excel.Application`

Comment: I tried early binding as well, and it didn't make a difference.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Does Excel start well itself at that problem machine under that problem user?

Comment: Yes, all the Office apps work perfectly by themselves.  We tried the Repair utility yesterday but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't find a real solution for this, but I "fixed" it by switching to the "Docmd.Transferspreadsheet" function.  It's not as robust as the original version (I can't specify that I want the header row in bold), but it works for all the users.

Thanks to everyone who commented!